# how can i call helper function of other module in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, dependency-injection

I have two modules (*amodule*, *bmodule*) and want to use an existing logic of *bmodule* in my current module *amodule*

I tried to use dependency injection in constructor, but i got an error on during runtime, because the parameter needed was the helper of the other module, but given was none.

```
class NewAction extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction
{

    private $_bhelper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement,
        \MyModule\bmodule\Helper\Data $bhelper
    )
    {

        $this->_bhelper = $bhelper;

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $subscriberFactory,
            $customerSession,
            $storeManager,
            $customerUrl,
            $customerAccountManagement
        );
    }

    ...
}

   [message] => Uncaught TypeError: Argument 7 passed to MyModules\amodule\Controller\NewAction::__construct() must be an instance of Mymodules\bmodule\Helper\Data, none given, called in
```

How can i make a cross call of another module logic?

In magento1 it was simply

```
Mage::helper('bmodule')->doMyStuff();
```

How can i do this correctly in Magento2?

Comment: Remove `var/generation` folder.

Comment: If you don't know what to clean - better clean whole var directory (except .htaccess file)

Answer (score 1):

Delete var/generation/vendor/yourmodule folder

**Magento 2 auto create Interceptor file for module's constructor class and after it check constructor class from Interceptor.php instead of your file.**

Run this command

```
rm -rf var/generation/vendor/youmodule*
```

**OR**

```
rm -rf var/generation/*
```

Then flush cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: @hexboxone You should accept an answer to help other developers to find their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error you are extending the class `\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction`. So you have to pass all parameters in construct of class you are extending. And Make sure you remove `var/generation/*` folder after that.

```
class NewAction extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction
{

    private $_bhelper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement,
        \MyModule\bmodule\Helper\Data $bhelper
    )
    {

        $this->_bhelper = $bhelper;

        // Pass $bhelper in parent construct

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $subscriberFactory,
            $customerSession,
            $storeManager,
            $customerUrl,
            $customerAccountManagement,
            $bhelper
        );
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Namespace\Module\Helper\Data;

class DefaultInvoice extends 
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\AbstractItems
 {
   protected $_dataHelper;

   public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
   Data $helperCustomdata,
   .....
   .....
   array $data = [])
   {       
    $this->_dataHelper = $helperCustomdata;       
    parent::__construct($context,
       ......
       .......
        $data);
   }
```

Then we can use this like

```
$enable_price_calc = $this->_dataHelper->isEnablePriceCalculation($product);
```